# How can i use multiple path parameters from serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to deploy my serverless app.
But have a problem like below.

```
An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceServicesServiceidVar - A sibling ({id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed
```

And below is my code.

```
updateApplication:
    handler: handler.updateApplication
    memorySize: 3008
    description: Update application
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: services/{serviceId}/applications/{applicationId}
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: authorize
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                serviceId: true
                applicationId: true
```

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785 - Looks like a problem with the CF is generate via serverless.

Comment: Thanks @MrkFldig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serverless framework seems to be complaining that you have defined the path parameters twice. Since you have declared it there directly below `-http:` you can remove the `request: parameters: paths:` block.

In other words, try this:

```
updateApplication:
    handler: handler.updateApplication
    memorySize: 3008
    description: Update application
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: services/{serviceId}/applications/{applicationId}
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: authorize
```

Happy coding!